# Animated scroll from left to right to specific id

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I am trying to get an animated scroll from left to right.
I know this question has been asked alot but mine is a bit different.
This website does not scroll horizontal, but it scrolls vertical and converting it to a horizontal scroll.

```
window.onscroll=function() {
    var scroll = window.scrollY;
    $('#page').css('left', '-' + scroll + 'px');
}
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/umAdeGI/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar question, see the answers here.  [Div scroll automatically on page load - Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912330/div-scroll-automatically-on-page-load-wordpress)

http://jsfiddle.net/BMb65/

This code worked best for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.scrolls//PUT YOUR DIV CLASS/ID or 'html, body'//').animate({ 
    scrollLeft: 4000
}, 100000, "linear");
});
```

My problem was two-fold though, in that I need to be able to stop the animation when the user interacts with the scrollbar.  Nothing I've found works so far though. :/

Comment: A bit too late for me but I hope someone might find this useful, thanks.