# Div scroll automatically on page load - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've currently got a div (.scrolls) with horizontal scrolling on a custom page template in wordpress.  Everything works great, but I want the div to automatically start slowly scrolling from left to right when the page loads.  I've looked into tinyscrollbar and a few others, but haven't been able to make anything work.  I'm using Thesis Theme, and while there's a place to put header scripts, I can't seem to get the coding right!

I'm a total jquery newb and can't find a simple tutorial that literally says "This exact code `<script>...</script>` goes here.  Can anyone help?

Comment: You can use CSS animations.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this in Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sL = $(this).width();
    $('.scrolls').animate({
        scrollLeft : sL
    },5000)
})
```

Just change the `5000` to set the time you want.

The demo **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ursGK/1/)**

Comment: Thanks so much!  This one seems to animate the best, however it only scrolls a portion of the width.  Right now, I can't stop the animation by interacting with the scrollbar, how do I do that?  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of moving the body of this page.

```
var movement = 0;  
setInterval(function () { 
$('body').css('margin-left', movement + 'px');
movement += -10; 
}, 400);
```

Run that in your console to see what happens.

Or you can use CSS Animations like so

```
@keyframes moveLeft
{
from {margin-left: 0;}
to {margin-left: -100px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveLeft /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {margin-left: 0;}
to {margin-left: -100px;}
}
#divToMove
{
animation: moveLeft 5s;
-webkit-animation: moveLeft 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Jquery` you can try this

```
$(".scrolls").animate({ scrollLeft: valueToScroll }, { duration: 200 } );
```

where `valueToScroll` should be how much you want to scroll